# Text Pre-processing Error: ['Errno 21] Is a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get all files from my directory and then run them through a series of def functions (python 3) and outputting each processed file into a certain directory. Below is my code:

```
   import re 
import glob
import sys
import string

#Create Stop_word Corpora
file1=open("/home/file/corps/stopwords.txt", 'rt', encoding='latin-1')
line= file1.read()
theWords=line.split()
stop_words=sorted(set(theWords)) # Stop Word Corpora

#Gather txt files to be processed
folder_path = "/home/file"
file_pattern = "/*txt"
folder_contents = glob.glob(folder_path + file_pattern)

#Read in the Txt Files
for file in folder_contents:
    print("Checking", file)
words= []
for file in folder_contents:
    read_file = open(file, 'rt', encoding='latin-1').read()
    words.extend(read_file.split())

def to_lowercase(words):
#"""Convert all characters to lowercase from list of tokenized words"""
    new_words=[]
    for word in words:
        new_word=word.lower()
        new_words.append(new_word)
    return new_words
def remove_punctuation(words):
#"""Remove punctuation from list of tokenized words"""
    new_words=[]
    for word in words:
        new_word = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', word)
        if new_word != '':
            new_words.append(new_word)
    return new_words
def replace_numbers(words):
#""""""Replace all interger occurrences in list of tokenized words with textual representation"
    new_words=[]
    for word in words:
        new_word= re.sub(" \d+", " ", word)
    if new_word !='':
        new_words.append(new_word)
    return new_words

def remove_stopwords(words):
#"""Remove stop words from list of tokenized words"""
    new_words=[]
    for word in words:
        if not word in stop_words:
            new_words.append(word)
    return new_words
def normalize(words):
    words = to_lowercase(words)

    words = remove_punctuation(words)

    words = replace_numbers(words)

    words = remove_stopwords(words)
    return words

words = normalize(words)

# Write the new procssed file to a different location
append_file=open("/home/file/Processed_Files",'a')
append_file.write("\n".join(words))
```

This is the error I keep receiving:

[image]

I want the new text files to be sent to the directory above, after they have been ran through the def functions. So there should be 5 new files in the Processed_files directory above.

Comment: I don't see `Error: 'Local Variable ...` on your screenshot - so you have wrong screenshot or wrong title.

Comment: use `print(words)` to see `words`. It is list and you can't add list to string "" (`"" + words`) You have to convert list to string - `str(words)` or better format it with `",".join(words)` or use module `csv` to save it as CSV file. It will add commas between words automatically.

Comment: Typo, changed the eroor name

Comment: Is there any way the the output could be 5 processed (ran thru code) txt files in the 'Processed_Files directory'? As of right now, the program runs but it outputs one empty file.

Comment: currently you try to write to folder `Processed_Files` but you have to write to file - ie. `Processed_Files/output.txt`. You should also check `print(words)` - maybe `words` is empty and it has nothing to write in file.

Comment: to make code more readble you should put all functions directly after import - before `file1 = open(..)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traceback you present doesn't agree with the error reported in your question title.

But your code does this twice:

```
for word in words:
    new_word = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', word)
if new_word != '':
    new_words.append(new_word)
```

If `words` is empty, then the `for word in words` loop never gets executed, even once. And if it doesn't get executed even once then no value ever gets assigned to `new_word`. So, in that case, when your code does `if new_word != '':` you will get the error `new_word referenced before assignment`. That is because your code is asking what is in `new_word` but it is unassigned.

This problem will go away if you code it like this:

```
for word in words:
    new_word = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', word)
    if new_word != '':
        new_words.append(new_word)
```

which I suspect is what you meant, anyway.

Comment: Is there any way the the output could be 5 processed (ran thru code) txt files in the 'Processed_Files directory'? As of right now, the program runs but it outputs one empty file.

Comment: If your program runs and does not produce the error `... is a directory` then I think you need to recast your question. Again. I answered a question about `new_word referenced before assignment` but then you changed that to `... is a directory` and now you say that the program runs. We can't really keep track of your problem if every time we answer a question you come back with a changed program and a different error. Understand, we're not looking over your shoulder.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest 3 changes:

1. Create an empty list and add all words to it

   ```
   words = []
   for file in folder_contents:
       read_file = open(file, 'rt', encoding='latin-1').read()
       words.extend(read_file.split())
   ```
2. Correctly convert a list into a str

   ```
   append_file.write("\n".join(words)))
   ```
3. Fix incorrect indentation

   ```
   words = normalize(words)
   ```

   and

   ```
   for word in words:
       new_word = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', word)
       if new_word != '':
           new_words.append(new_word)
   ```

Comment: Is there any way the the output could be 5 processed (ran thru code) txt files in the 'Processed_Files directory'? As of right now, the program runs but it outputs one empty file.

Comment: You maybe need to close the append_file at the end. `append_file.close()`